# Get call details from blackberry servers

Tags: blackberry

Can anybody let me know how to capture mobile calls and e-mails from a Blackberry connected to a BES server

Comment: What details are you looking for, and what servers are you talking about?

Comment: I need call details (do you understand what does this means (start and end time)). I need these details for some of the blackberry phones. is this possible

Comment: I do not know why this question is voted -1 :(

Answer (score 0):

That information should be available from the [PhoneLogs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/package-summary.html).

Comment: This is a phone application. I need data from web show that I can use it further

Comment: I doubt the information would be available from the web. Phone log data and emails can be captured using the Blackberry API.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you're looking to be able to get a phone's call log using the BES server to retrieve the information?  If this is so, doesn't the BES server offer this functionality out of the box?